# While I'm trying do pdo connection a host name is changed

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I trying to do connection to a database using PDO:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=sql.hostname.com;dbname=host', 'host', 'host');
```

And error i am getting on website is:

> Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'host'@'host.hostname.com' (using password: YES)

So why does it changes sql. to host. or this isn't causing a problem?

Comment: (Login and password are correct)

Answer (score 0):

'host'@'host.hostname.com' is just an email address for the 'host' account.  If you change the name the address will change too

If you are using a local server for development such as WAMP or XAMPP, you can try to use the `root` user to make sure it works.